# OrientDB.RequestError: Cannot find a command executor for the command request: sql.#11.1

Tags: orientdb, oriento

I am experimenting with OrientDB (community edition v1.7-rc2) / Oriento (0.4.0)

The function

```
function linkChildToParent(oChild, oParent) {
    return (
        oDB.edge.from(oChild).to(oParent)
        .create({"@class": 'OrgUnit_isPartOf_OrgUnit'})
        .tap(log)
        .return(oChild)
    );
}
```

Fails with an exception

```
C:\Users\Udo\workspace\NodeOrient\node_modules\oriento\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\async.js:93
                throw res.e;
                         ^
OrientDB.RequestError: Cannot find a command executor for the command request: sql.#11.1
    at Operation.parseError (C:\Users\Udo\workspace\NodeOrient\node_modules\oriento\lib\transport\binary\protocol\operation.js:806:13)
    at Operation.consume (C:\Users\Udo\workspace\NodeOrient\node_modules\oriento\lib\transport\binary\protocol\operation.js:396:35)
    at Connection.process (C:\Users\Udo\workspace\NodeOrient\node_modules\oriento\lib\transport\binary\connection.js:324:17)
    at Connection.handleSocketData (C:\Users\Udo\workspace\NodeOrient\node_modules\oriento\lib\transport\binary\connection.js:250:17)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:764:14)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:426:10)
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:422:5)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:165:9)
From previous event:
    at Function.Promise$All [as all] (C:\Users\Udo\workspace\NodeOrient\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:193:12)
    at generateDependents (C:\Users\Udo\workspace\NodeOrient\setupOrgDB.js:202:35)
From previous event:
    at Function.Promise$Join [as join] (C:\Users\Udo\workspace\NodeOrient\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\join.js:118:15)
    at BinaryTransport.populateDB (C:\Users\Udo\workspace\NodeOrient\setupOrgDB.js:219:20)
```

So I debugged into the driver till I found

```
function createEdge (db, config, from, to) {
  var command = "CREATE EDGE",
      className, attributes;
  config = edgeConfig(config);
  className = config[0];
  attributes = config[1];
  command += ' ' + className + ' FROM ' + edgeReference(from)  + ' TO ' + edgeReference(to);

  if (attributes) {
    command += ' CONTENT ' + JSON.stringify(attributes);
  }

  return db.query(command);
}
```

The content of command right before `return db.query(command);` is

```
CREATE EDGE OrgUnit_isPartOf_OrgUnit FROM (#11.1) TO (#11.0)
```

I then used the (browser based) console to verify that OrgUnit_isPartOf_OrgUnit actually inherits from Edge. I also verified that it will link OrgUnit with OrgUnit Vertices and that OrgUnit is derived from Vertex. I also double verified that records #11.1 and #11.0 are actually present in the database.

Then I issued

```
CREATE EDGE OrgUnit_isPartOf_OrgUnit FROM (#11.1) TO (#11.0)
```

directly in the console and got

```
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandExecutorNotFoundException: Cannot find a command executor for the command request: sql.#11:1
```

This is basically the same exception. With Google I found some [Javadoc for this exception](http://www.orientdb.org/releases/latest/javadoc/com/orientechnologies/orient/core/command/class-use/OCommandExecutorNotFoundException.html). However this did not help me at all.

What is wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right command should be without parenthesis. Parenthesis executes sub-queries:

```
CREATE EDGE OrgUnit_isPartOf_OrgUnit FROM #11:1 TO #11:0
```

For more information look at [Create Edge](http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/orientdb.wiki/SQL-Create-Edge.html) command.

Comment: Interesting. Now I have to figure out why the query builder put in the paranthesis. But this definitely caused the issue.